# Problems configuring OpenVPN to use the public IP and LAN as their own, for clients

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, windows-11, openvpn

I ran into a problem when configuring an OpenVPN server to use my public IP address and access devices on my local network through that server. My goal is to allow users to use my public IP and access devices between 192.168.0.100-192.168.0.255 from anywhere in the world. I already have configuration files for the server and client, and have port 1194 open for connections.

When using the `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` option in server.ovpn, users cannot access any sites.
Without this setting, their public IP address does not change and they cannot access my local network.

Here is my current server configuration (server.ovpn):

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\SERVER.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\SERVER.key"
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\easytls\\tls-auth.key" 0
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh.pem"



server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0

topology subnet
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 6
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

And the client configuration (client.ovpn):

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

remote <my-ip> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-auth tls-auth.key 1

remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.100
```

Notes: the OpenVPN server should not be running on 192.168.0.1 to avoid blocking access to my router. I have also made sure that "Ethernet - Properties" is checked and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter is set to 1.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Please help me to understand. Thank you!